# How to insert quotes in a list?

Tags: string, list, vim, filter

I'm trying to insert these special characters in a list:

```
let special_character = '[%!?(){}<>*+&:;^|#$€§°@\/[]=.,-_'"]'
```

like this:

```
let list = []
call insert(list, special_character)
```

and filter this list out with a string.
p.e.

```
let string = '<()*'"'
```

using:

```
let newlist = filter(copy(list), 'v:key =~# ".string."')
```

I know I have to escape most specialcharacters to insert them in a list or filter them out, but how do I insert a quote (') or double quote (") in a list and filter them out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand what you want to achieve, but:

1. Double the single quote to handle it inside strings or lists.
2. Use `v:val` to filter a list. `v:key` is for a dictionary.

Here you have a small example that could help you. It doesn't use all those strange characters but it use the quotes you ask for. Join them with pipes to execute them as a single `ex` command:

```
:let special_character = 'abcd_''"'
:let list = split(special_character, '\zs')
:echo list
:let newlist = filter(copy(list), 'v:val =~# "''"')
:echo newlist[0]
```

It yields:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '_', '''', '"']
'
```

Note how the single quote is escaped in a list, but not when printed. Also the use of `v:val`. To filter a double quote simply escape it with backslash (I wasn't sure of that but tested it). And also note that I split the string, because otherwise the `filter` function only will execute once for the string with all symbols. These way will run for each element of the list.

**EDIT** to add the example of the double quote:

```
:let newlist = filter(copy(list), 'v:val =~# "\""') | echo newlist[0]
```

It yields:

```
"
```

Comment: Thank you for your explication!